# jQuery on table div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table as follows:

```html
<table class="mytable">
  <div>
    <tr>
      <th>h1</th>
      <th>h1-1</th>
      <th>h1-2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>h2</th>
      <th>h2-2</th>
      <th>h2-3</th>
    </tr>
  </div>
  <div>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</table>
```

Now I want two jQuery code snippets as follows:

1. jQuery to get all div present in table.
2. jQuery to get first tr's td data in every div. it may be in loop.

I am new to jQuery.

Comment: Shoot at sight the divs. We cannot help you without code that you tried with.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post code and effort. Now your question belongs at elance.com. Also the HTML is invalid

Comment: You are not allowed to put a div inside a table directly. That is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried but this could help:

1. `$(".mytable div")`
2. `$(".mytable div tr:first td").each(function(){
    var data= $(this).text();
   })`

Also your html is not valid. You need not have div tag, instead you can have `<thead>` or `<tbody>` tags inside table. `<div>` tag should be used in td tag, when using inside table.